# Configure a queue for customl retry messages in Rebus

Tags: rebus

I was able to write a custom retry policy, using sql server as the deferred message storage. But now, for the scalability reasons I would like to run multiple workers(message handler tasks) deployed over different machines. Due to that reason I would like to have a central place to read deferred messages(like from a queue) rather than reading from sql server.

Is there any way to store the deferred messages in a queue? Is that a better approach? What would be the better approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to store the deferred messages in a queue? Is that a better approach?

Not with any queues I am familiar with :) Most queues are really good at [fifo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), which conflicts with deferred messages in that the delay can vary on a per-message basis (at least in the general case).

The desire to access messages ordered potentially very differently from the order they were sent, makes databases with secondary indexes a pretty good technology for storing deferred messages.

> What would be the better approach to do this?

I am not sure I understand what you think is wrong with storing deferred messages in SQL Server, though.

Of course, if you have many endpoints deferring messages, you might want to use an "external timeout manager" instead of having each individual endpoint poll the database – this can be had by doing this in your endpoints:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Timeouts(t => t.UseExternalTimeoutManager("timeouts"))
    .Start();
```

and then simply start an endpoint with a configured timeout storage and the input queue `timeouts`.

Comment: I like the solution of having external timeout manager and that is what I was looking for (rather than each worker polling database). But may I know where this external timeout manager is running? If that timeout manager crashes, will the rest of workers elect another timeout manager?

Comment: If the timeout manager stops or crashes without being restarted, no endpoints will receive their deferred messages. New deferred messages will simply queue up in the `timeouts` queue. The timeout manager is simply an ordinary Rebus endpoint, which _you_ need to make.

Comment: If you use a central database, like e.g. SQL Server, and if you use some kind of broker-based queueing system (lige e.g. RabbitMQ) it is pretty straightforward to deploy two timeout manager instances on two different machines to implement redundancy

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!